# Unity: How do I set a png to GL quad as a texture 2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, opengl

Here is what I want to do:
I want to load a PNG (with a transparent background) and set it as a texture to the quad. I need to do all of this programatically.

Here is my attempt.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.XR;

public class GLTest : MonoBehaviour
{
   // Start is called before the first frame update
   static Material mat;
    static Material texMat;
    float z;
    float W;
    float H;
    Matrix4x4 projectionMatrix;
    Texture2D letter;
    Renderer pepe;

   void Start(){
        W = 2480.0f;
        H = 2416.0f;
        projectionMatrix = Matrix4x4.Ortho(0, (int)W, (int)H, 0, -1, 100);  
      Shader shader = Shader.Find("Hidden/Internal-Colored");
        //Shader shader2 = Shader.Find("Custom/MyShader2");
        Shader shader2 = Shader.Find("Standard");

        if (shader2 == null){
            Debug.Log("Null shader again");
        }

      mat = new Material(shader);
        texMat = new Material(shader2);

        if (texMat == null){
            Debug.Log("Tex Mat is NULL");
        }

      mat.hideFlags = HideFlags.HideAndDontSave;
        texMat.hideFlags = HideFlags.HideAndDontSave;
      
      // Turn backface culling off
      mat.SetInt("_Cull", (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.CullMode.Off);
        texMat.SetInt("_Cull", (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.CullMode.Off);
      
        // Turn off depth writes
      mat.SetInt("_ZWrite", 0);   
        texMat.SetInt("_ZWrite", 0);   

      z = 30.0f;    

        letter = new Texture2D(2, 2);
        //ImageConversion.LoadImage(letter,bytes);

      byte[] pngBytes = new byte[]
      {
          0x89, 0x50, 0x4E, 0x47, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x1A, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0D, 0x49, 0x48, 0x44, 0x52,
          0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x40, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x40, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x8F, 0x02, 0x2E,
          0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x57, 0x49, 0x44, 0x41, 0x54, 0x78, 0x01, 0xA5, 0x57, 0xD1, 0xAD, 0xC4,
          0x30, 0x08, 0x83, 0x81, 0x32, 0x4A, 0x66, 0xC9, 0x36, 0x99, 0x85, 0x45, 0xBC, 0x4E, 0x74, 0xBD,
          0x8F, 0x9E, 0x5B, 0xD4, 0xE8, 0xF1, 0x6A, 0x7F, 0xDD, 0x29, 0xB2, 0x55, 0x0C, 0x24, 0x60, 0xEB,
          0x0D, 0x30, 0xE7, 0xF9, 0xF3, 0x85, 0x40, 0x74, 0x3F, 0xF0, 0x52, 0x00, 0xC3, 0x0F, 0xBC, 0x14,
          0xC0, 0xF4, 0x0B, 0xF0, 0x3F, 0x01, 0x44, 0xF3, 0x3B, 0x3A, 0x05, 0x8A, 0x41, 0x67, 0x14, 0x05,
          0x18, 0x74, 0x06, 0x4A, 0x02, 0xBE, 0x47, 0x54, 0x04, 0x86, 0xEF, 0xD1, 0x0A, 0x02, 0xF0, 0x84,
          0xD9, 0x9D, 0x28, 0x08, 0xDC, 0x9C, 0x1F, 0x48, 0x21, 0xE1, 0x4F, 0x01, 0xDC, 0xC9, 0x07, 0xC2,
          0x2F, 0x98, 0x49, 0x60, 0xE7, 0x60, 0xC7, 0xCE, 0xD3, 0x9D, 0x00, 0x22, 0x02, 0x07, 0xFA, 0x41,
          0x8E, 0x27, 0x4F, 0x31, 0x37, 0x02, 0xF9, 0xC3, 0xF1, 0x7C, 0xD2, 0x16, 0x2E, 0xE7, 0xB6, 0xE5,
          0xB7, 0x9D, 0xA7, 0xBF, 0x50, 0x06, 0x05, 0x4A, 0x7C, 0xD0, 0x3B, 0x4A, 0x2D, 0x2B, 0xF3, 0x97,
          0x93, 0x35, 0x77, 0x02, 0xB8, 0x3A, 0x9C, 0x30, 0x2F, 0x81, 0x83, 0xD5, 0x6C, 0x55, 0xFE, 0xBA,
          0x7D, 0x19, 0x5B, 0xDA, 0xAA, 0xFC, 0xCE, 0x0F, 0xE0, 0xBF, 0x53, 0xA0, 0xC0, 0x07, 0x8D, 0xFF,
          0x82, 0x89, 0xB4, 0x1A, 0x7F, 0xE5, 0xA3, 0x5F, 0x46, 0xAC, 0xC6, 0x0F, 0xBA, 0x96, 0x1C, 0xB1,
          0x12, 0x7F, 0xE5, 0x33, 0x26, 0xD2, 0x4A, 0xFC, 0x41, 0x07, 0xB3, 0x09, 0x56, 0xE1, 0xE3, 0xA1,
          0xB8, 0xCE, 0x3C, 0x5A, 0x81, 0xBF, 0xDA, 0x43, 0x73, 0x75, 0xA6, 0x71, 0xDB, 0x7F, 0x0F, 0x29,
          0x24, 0x82, 0x95, 0x08, 0xAF, 0x21, 0xC9, 0x9E, 0xBD, 0x50, 0xE6, 0x47, 0x12, 0x38, 0xEF, 0x03,
          0x78, 0x11, 0x2B, 0x61, 0xB4, 0xA5, 0x0B, 0xE8, 0x21, 0xE8, 0x26, 0xEA, 0x69, 0xAC, 0x17, 0x12,
          0x0F, 0x73, 0x21, 0x29, 0xA5, 0x2C, 0x37, 0x93, 0xDE, 0xCE, 0xFA, 0x85, 0xA2, 0x5F, 0x69, 0xFA,
          0xA5, 0xAA, 0x5F, 0xEB, 0xFA, 0xC3, 0xA2, 0x3F, 0x6D, 0xFA, 0xE3, 0xAA, 0x3F, 0xEF, 0xFA, 0x80,
          0xA1, 0x8F, 0x38, 0x04, 0xE2, 0x8B, 0xD7, 0x43, 0x96, 0x3E, 0xE6, 0xE9, 0x83, 0x26, 0xE1, 0xC2,
          0xA8, 0x2B, 0x0C, 0xDB, 0xC2, 0xB8, 0x2F, 0x2C, 0x1C, 0xC2, 0xCA, 0x23, 0x2D, 0x5D, 0xFA, 0xDA,
          0xA7, 0x2F, 0x9E, 0xFA, 0xEA, 0xAB, 0x2F, 0xDF, 0xF2, 0xFA, 0xFF, 0x01, 0x1A, 0x18, 0x53, 0x83,
          0xC1, 0x4E, 0x14, 0x1B, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x49, 0x45, 0x4E, 0x44, 0xAE, 0x42, 0x60, 0x82,
      };


        letter.LoadImage(pngBytes);
        Debug.Log("Textrue size: " + letter.width + "x" + letter.height);

        //mat.EnableKeyword ("_MainTex");

   }

    void OnRenderObject(){

      GL.PushMatrix();
        GL.LoadIdentity();      
        GL.MultMatrix(transform.localToWorldMatrix);      
        GL.MultMatrix(Camera.main.projectionMatrix);
        GL.MultMatrix(projectionMatrix);

      mat.SetColor("_Color", Color.gray);
        mat.SetPass(0);
        GL.Begin(GL.QUADS);
        GL.Vertex3(0,0,z);
        GL.Vertex3(W,0,z);
        GL.Vertex3(W,H,z);
        GL.Vertex3(0,H,z);
        GL.End();

        float w = 500.0f;
        float h = 600.0f;
        float x = (W-w)/2;
        float y = (H-h)/2;

      //mat.SetColor("_Color", Color.blue);
        texMat.SetTexture("_MainTex", letter);
        texMat.SetPass(0);

        GL.Begin(GL.QUADS);
        GL.TexCoord2(x,y); 
        GL.Vertex3(x,y,z);
        
        GL.TexCoord2(x+w,y); 
        GL.Vertex3(x+w,y,z);
        
        GL.TexCoord2(x+w,y+h); 
        GL.Vertex3(x+w,y+h,z);
        
        GL.TexCoord2(x,y+h); 
        GL.Vertex3(x,y+h,z);
        GL.End();


        GL.PopMatrix();


    }


}
```

I draw two quads. The second one should have the png enconded unity logo that I got from: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ImageConversion.LoadImage.html

As was suggeted I'm using the standard shader. HOwever All I see is a black quad. So the problem is either with the shader or with the way I define the tex quad coordinates.

Can anyone help me?

If the shader is the issue where would I be able to find a shader that will allow me to show the picture?

EDIT: I have been at least able to switch to a standard shader and see a black triangle and took the image out of the picture so no possibility of image loading issues exist.

Comment: [`Internal-Colored`](https://github.com/TwoTailsGames/Unity-Built-in-Shaders/blob/master/DefaultResources/Internal-Colored.shader) has no texture support yes ... use a different one

Comment: I just tried creating a new unlit shader. Left it as is (I've no idea how to code shader) and I was able to create a new material but instead of showing me the picture all I see is a lighter gray square. So either the shader is bad or the image is being loaded incorrectly.

Comment: Try with a built-in shader that supports a texture (e.g. Standard ^^) .. but it sounds more like the loading failed

Comment: @derHugo How can I try with the Standard built in shader, programatically? Do you have some code? Also I tried saving the image as bmp so encoding would not be an issue and now I see the square as all black. So the shader is definitely the issue here.

Comment: `Shader.Find("Standard")` ... also why load this image in like that at all? It sounds like it is sitting within the `Assets` folder anyway so why not rather expose the `public Texture2D image;` in the Inspector and drag your image in the slot?

Comment: @derHugo. I just ried using standard. Same thing. All I see is black box. In the example code I put in a fictiional path. In the final product the image is something that I is basically user input. I know the image is theere. And I checke that enumber of bytes read corresponds to the image size. Why would it not show?

Comment: @derHugo. Thanks I tried with the standard and got a black square. Also I substitutted the image with the png enconded unity logo from the docs so we now know image loading is not an issue.

Comment: yea I also tested and texture nor shader seems to b the issue really but rather how `OnRenderObject` works ... just for trying: Have you tried replacing `Camera.main` by `Camera.current`?

Comment: @derHugo I assume you meant in the matrix multiplication? Because I don't use it anywhere else. I just ried it and it's the smae thing. You believe chaning OnRenderObject to another method might make a difference?

Comment: hm honestly I don't know much about GL and those renderer methods :/ The most obvious for me was only the shader .. beyond that I am just wildly guessing around tbh :D

Comment: Why use the equivalent to _OpenGL Immediate Mode?_  It's rather slow.

Comment: @MickyD I'm not sure what to say. I need this to draw 2D static images basically. Do you have an alternative?

Comment: I highly encourage you to use `Mesh`. 
 Using Immediate Mode to send geometry and textures every frame is quite inefficient. 
 https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.html

Comment: @MickyD, could you provide an example on how to create a TextMesh programatically (no UI) and the position it on a specific place on the monitor? This is my task right now, and seeing that there is a TextMesh it would solve all my issues.