# Unity: Add a Text Using a TextMesh Via Script?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I just want to be able to see some text rendered in the world.

The only example code that I've found is this:

```
  GameObject Text = new GameObject();      
  TextMesh textMesh = Text.AddComponent<TextMesh>();
  textMesh.font = new Font();
  mat.SetColor("_Color", Color.black);
  mat.SetPass(0);       
  meshRenderer.material = mat;
  textMesh.text = "Hello World!";
```

Where mat is defined by the code:

```
  Shader shader = Shader.Find("Hidden/Internal-Colored");
  mat = new Material(shader);
  mat.hideFlags = HideFlags.HideAndDontSave;     
  mat.SetInt("_Cull", (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.CullMode.Off);
  mat.SetInt("_ZWrite", 0);   
  mat.SetColor("_Color", Color.blue);
  mat.SetPass(0);
```

This code is added to the Start of MonoBevaviour. And the script is tied to Game Main camera.

No text appears anywhere that I can see.

Comment: Why not rather create one in the editor, create a prefab from it and then instantiate the prefab? Or this is specifically for some 
custom  editor scripting? In general `TextMesh` is legacy and you should rather use `TextMeshPro`

Comment: @hijinxbassist [`TextMesh`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextMesh.html) != [`UI.Text`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-Text.html) .. it doesn't require this

Comment: @derHugo. I'm on a very specific situations. I need to show VR stuff but the VR headset needs to function as a regular 2D Monitor. So I need to draw everythign as if it were a monitor including text. Since what I needd to draw (other than text) are very very simple shapes, the text is the last challenge I need to solve. The text is very varied in both size and color so I need a flexible solution. Is adding a prefab compatible with all of this?

Comment: Hm .. you would usually just use a `Screenspace Overlay` canvas .. but Unity states this isn't rendered in XR mode since it would literally sit in your face of course .. so I understand the troubles you have .. interesting use case though maybe if you describe that further in your question(s)  someone knows a more proper solution that solves all your issues at once ^^ Unfortunately I'm doubting that one would be me in the moment

Comment: But to answer: it makes no difference in the results whether you construct your gameObject from scratch via code .. or instantiate an existing prefab which is probably easier to configure via the Inspector and also uses Unity's built-in default materials and settings etc ... So yeah I would claim using a prefab is probably easier

Comment: @derHugo I try not to go into too much details on my question. The more specific the better. Otherwise it becmoes on "How do I solve my problem" question and it gets no answers and/or a lot of downvotes. Also I have asked othere related questions on different attempst to draw text on screen. inlcuding using canvas which is the recommende way to use text in VR. However, I got notthign when I tried it out (nothing got rendered)

Comment: In this case I am still interested in what your specific use case looks like .. as said maybe there are alternative ways to approach this

Answer (score 0):

Ah I think I might have something.

I am not sure though if this works for VR devices - I know that Unity e.g. doesn't render Screenspace overlay canvas on XR.

But back to the point: There is a legacy UI system which is usually not used anymore except for in editor Inspector scripting [IMGUI](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GUIScriptingGuide.html)

I think it might actually fit your very special need using [GUILayout.Label](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUILayout.Label.html) you should be able to draw a flat label onto the screen even in VR.

With [GUI.Label](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.Label.html) you have full control over the pixel coordinates and size.

```
public class YourTextDrawer : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnGUI() 
    {
        var color = GUI.color;
        GUI.color = Color.green;
        var textPosition = new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 150, Screen.height / 2 - 100, 300, 200);
        GUI.Label(textPosition, "Hello World!");
        GUI.color = color;
    }
}
```

*Not tested, just scrabbling this down from memory right now*

---

And actually thinking about it, this might even work for [your image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74342938/unity-how-do-i-set-a-png-to-gl-quad-as-a-texture-2d) as well

Comment: Thanks for the try. But anything on the OnGUI function is simply not rendered in VR. I tried it anyway just in case. I does do what I want, though.

Comment: @aarelovich arrr sad ^^ I was already kinda expecting that but was worth a shot